# Any chance to use standard library #include <concepts> with clang

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

At [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) there is a clang version called
"x86-64 clang (experimental concepts)", providing experimental core language concept features.

Is there also a way to use (an experimental version of) the standard library implementation?

It would be great to have `std::convertible_to` and friends available when designing concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me  that GCC is a bit more ahead implementing C++20 features. [You can check online](https://godbolt.org/z/w4Ta6N) that the following code runs using GCC (trunk):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T> concept scalar = std::is_scalar_v<T>;

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T t) requires scalar<T>: _t{t} { std::cout << "is scalar" <<std::endl; }
    Foo(T t) requires (not scalar<T>): _t{t} { std::cout << "is not scalar" <<std::endl;}
private:
    T _t;
};

class cls {};

int main() 
{
    Foo{true};
    Foo{'d'};
    Foo{3.14159};
    cls c;
    Foo{c};

    return 0;
}
```